# How do I connect my AngularJS template HTML files to the main Javascript file loaded in the main page so that the ng-controller directives are found?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, eclipse

I am using the AngularJS Eclipse plugin, and creating HTML templates for use in my project.

It has a master Javascript which loads AngularJS and is included in the main page. However when I create the other template files (which are HTML fragments loaded via the AngularJS Routing directives) the HTML/AngularJS validator fails to resolve the controller name and generates an error in the Problems Tab.

[image: Inline error in the HTML]
[image: Error logged in the Problems Tab]

The code still works when run, but I want to ensure the validator doesn't throw these errors. Is there a way I can configure the AngularJS plugin to resolve these correctly, or can I somehow link them another way?

In the project properties, the main JS file (home.js) is included in the JavaScript Include Path and in the Tern Script Paths.

E.g., The ng-controller ***AgentLoginCtrl*** is not found in the below HTML (which is in its own file). It is defined in the global JavaScript file. How do I link these files together so that the name is resolved properly?

```
<div ng-cloak layout="row" layout-align="center center">
<form ng-controller="AgentLoginCtrl" name="userForm" style="width: 300px; background-color: white; border: 2px solid rgb(142, 169, 222); padding: 0px 5px 5px 5px">
    <div layout="column" layout-align="top left">
        <h2 flex>Agent Login</h2>
        <md-input-container flex class="md-block" style="margin: 5px 0px 0px 0px"> 
            <label>User Login</label>
            <input name="login" ng-model="user.login" autocomplete="username" required/>
            <div ng-messages="userForm.login.$error">
                <div ng-message="required">User Login is required.</div>
            </div>
        </md-input-container>
        <md-input-container flex class="md-block" style="margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px">
            <label>Password</label>
            <input name="password" type="password" ng-model="user.password" autocomplete="current-password" required/>
            <div ng-messages="userForm.password.$error">
                <div ng-message="required">Password is required.</div>
            </div>
        </md-input-container>
        <md-button class="md-primary" ng-click="login(user)">LOG IN</md-button>
        <div class="ng-hide errorMessage" ng-show="loginFailed">Login Failed - Please try again</div>
        <div class="ng-hide errorMessage" ng-show="validationFailed">Input Invalid - Please correct and resubmit</div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I wasn't specifying the app.

Adding the attribute ng-app="WebApp" before the ng-controller attribute fixed the problem:

```
<form ng-app="WebApp" ng-controller="AgentLoginCtrl" name="userForm" style="width: 300px; background-color: white; border: 2px solid rgb(142, 169, 222); padding: 0px 5px 5px 5px">
```